# showing unexpected token in looping through arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am a javascript newbie. I have to create a var `pets` with an array `['cat', 'dog', 'rat']` and by using for loop I have make each strings in that array plural.

**My code is:**

```
var pets = ['cat', 'dog', 'rat'];
for (pets[i] = pets[i] + 's';) {    

};
console.log(pets);
```

**Error is:**

```
for (pets[i] = pets[i] + 's';) {    
                         ^
Could not run: Unexpected token )
```

Comment: Start with proper [for-loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) syntax

Comment: `for (pets[i] = pets[i] + 's';)` huh? see [MDN for doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

Answer (score 4):

The syntax of the [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop is incorrect. It'll throw Syntax Errors.

The Correct syntax is:

```
for ([initialization]; [condition]; [final-expression])
    statement
```

**Updated Code:**

```
for(var i = 0; i < pets.length; i++) {
    pets[i] = pets[i] + 's';
}
```

You can even write this in single line, taking advantage of the last expression of the `for` which is evaluated after each iteration.

```
for(var i = 0; i < pets.length; pets[i] = pets[i] + 's', i++);
```

**Note:** Multiple expression are separated by using `,`-comma operator.

Comment: `for(var i = 0; i < pets.length; pets[i] = pets[i] + 's',i++);` shortened little bit.

Answer (score 3):

Your for loop is messed up, it can surely be done using `for-loop` but I would suggest you to use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
var pets = ['cat', 'dog', 'rat'];
pets = pets.map(function(el){
   return el+"s";
});
```

> The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a
>   provided function on every element in this array.

**In ECMAScript2015** arrow function

```
var pets = ['cat', 'dog', 'rat'];
pets = pets.map( el => el+"s");
```

If you still feel like using for loop and want to write some unnecessary code then do:

```
for(var i = 0; i < pets.length; i++){
  pets[i] = pets[i] + 's';
}
```

Comment: hey buddy i have to use for loop to iterate through arrays

Comment: Or, using fat arrow syntax: `pets.map(el => el + 's')`;

Comment: This solution is better, but not for a newbie who cannot even properly write a loop :)

Comment: @Sagar: *why* do you "*have to use for loop*"? This answer does precisely what you asked for; if there are artificial and pointless restrictions add those to the question, don't expect us to guess your requirements.